# Can I use motors without encoders (open loop) for base of robot?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, base-odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have read that i need to publish odometry data so that the robot knows its current position. I have encoders built into the motor so I know that the steps i am sending will be accurate. Is there a way I can publish the goal state as the current state and will that work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301584/can-i-use-motors-without-encoders-(open-loop)-for-base-of-robot?/) by [Ark-tic12](https://answers.ros.org/users/37163/ark-tic12/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-08-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As to open loop in ROS -- yes and no. It really depends on what you are trying to do.

Most things like mapping and the navigation stack (move_base) assume that you have odometry (typically published as TF data). Often, this comes from encoders. This is mainly due to the fact that good encoders generally are the easiest and cheapest approach to good odometry. There is a [tutorial on publishing odometry on the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom).

There are some other options for generating odometry. If you have a laser scanner, you can run a [scan matcher like this one](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_scan_matcher) to output odometry. But I'm going to assume that if you have the sophistication of a laser scanner, you probably might as well put good encoders on the robot (that scan matching package was mainly developed for drones, for which encoders really aren't an option).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2018-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1